# linux x86_64 nasm assembly syscalls

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I have found charts online showing various syscalls for x86_64 linux nasm assembly and there appears to be 380ish total syscalls, however every book or tutorial I can find only "how a few of the syscalls work and what they do?" Does anyone know where I can find information on every single syscall for x86_64 linux assembly using the nasm assembler?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Linux man pages (section 2).  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html

It doesn't matter what assembler (or C compiler) you use to create x86-64 machine code, the system calls you can make are the same.  (Put a call number in RAX and run the `syscall` instruction; inside the kernel it uses that number to index a table of function pointers.  Or returns `-ENOSYS` if it's out of range.)

**Debug your program with `strace ./my_program` to trace the system calls it makes.**  This decodes the args and return values into meaningful stuff on a per-call basis, so you can easily see if you passed a bad pointer making the syscall return `-EFAULT` for example.  (System calls don't raise SIGSEGV / segfault, they just return an error.)

---

`/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` has the actual numbers.  (Included by `<asm/unistd.h>` when compiling for 64-bit).  The man pages will document the args in terms of C syntax.  **Given the C prototype, you can work out the asm ABI according to the x86-64 System V ABI**.  (Same as the function-call ABI except with R10 instead of RCX for the 4th arg, if present.)  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6)

`syscall(2)` is a glibc wrapper function for system calls, and [**the syscall man page**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) also documents is asm ABI for various Linux platforms (x86-64, SPARC, ARM, etc.), including registers for the call number and ret val, and the instruction for entering the kernel.  Note that the function name being the same as the x86-64 `syscall` instruction is just a coincidence.

---

**Nobody bothers to make exhaustive documentation for every system call for every different flavour of asm syntax** - the information is all there in the man pages plus the calling convention doc; the NOTES section of the Linux man pages document differences between the C library wrapper API vs. the underlying asm system call.

See also https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/ for more including VDSO stuff for efficient `getpid` / `clock_gettime` without even entering the kernel.

However, some people do compile tables of system call name and Linux x86-64 call number and arg registers.  I've never found that useful (the syscall calling convention is so close to the function calling convention that it's easy to remember), but **https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/ is there if you want it.**

---

Notable differences between the POSIX function and the raw Linux system call exist for a couple calls: For example [`brk` / `sbrk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html), and also [`getpriority`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpriority.2.html) where the "nice" level return values are biased so they're not in the `-4095..-1` range of error codes.  **But most system calls have an ABI that exactly matches the C library wrapper prototype** in which case the NOTES section doesn't mention anything.

Comment: If all I can find on the web and in books is just how a few syscalls work out of 300+ total syscalls then how is it possible to ever learn assembly?

Comment: @Spencer_J: That's a non-sequitur.  There's lots of material on how to learn asm in general.  Once you understand asm and calling conventions, it's straightforward to read any Linux man page and know how to invoke it from asm.  (Because they all follow a standard calling convention for mapping C args to asm, and that is documented in the ABI.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](//stackoverflow.com/q/2535989))

Comment: Unfortunately, even man pages are sometimes wrong. Compare for instance `struct stat` described in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html with the real structure discovered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216616/get-file-size-with-stat-syscall
The order of structure members **st_mode** and **st_nlink** is swapped in manual pages.