# Why does stat system call return 0 for st_size in NASM

Tags: macos, system-calls, stat

I have been trying to use stat in NASM to get file sizes. However, st_size returns 0. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
global _main
extern _printf

section .bss
    stat resb 144

section .text
    filename:
        db "test.asm", 0   ; The name of this NASM file

    format:
        db "%lld", 10, 0

    _main:
        mov rax, 0x20000bc   ; system call for stat
        mov rdi, filename
        mov rsi, stat
        syscall   ; returns 0

        push rax
        mov rdi, format
        mov rsi, stat
        mov rsi, [rsi + 96]   ; the offset of st_size in __DARWIN_STRUCT_STAT64 as defined in <sys/stat.h> is 96
        call _printf
        pop rax

        ret
```

This is not a duplicate of [Get file size with stat syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216616/get-file-size-with-stat-syscall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syscall. That's the one for backward compatibility with the 32-bit-sized structure. Of course, that means that the `st_size` field is not at the offset your code is expecting.

The `stat()` function's symbol name is not `_stat`, by default, since 10.6. Rather, it's `_stat$INODE64`. If you look at the assembly for that in `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib`, you'll find that it uses the syscall value `0x2000152`.

Comment: That works, but how do i look into the assembly for a dylib? `Objdump -d` doesn't work.

Comment: It should work to use `otool -tV`. Also, try using the `-macho` option to `objdump` to tell it the file format (i.e. `objdump -macho -d`).